# SqlBulkCopy not getting RollBack

Tags: c#, .net, sql, transactions, sqlbulkcopy

Actually,I have used `SqlBulkCopy` for inserting rows into my `DB` and I have placed transactions to the `SqlBulkCopy`.
Now,My Scenario is that,I have a `DataTable` containing `500k` rows and I'm trying to insert them through `SqlBulkCopy`.

My Code :

```
using (con)
{
   con.Open();
   using (SqlTransaction transaction = con.BeginTransaction())
   {
      using (SqlBulkCopy SBC = new SqlBulkCopy(con, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, transaction))
       {
         SBC.DestinationTableName = "SURVEY_EMAIL_BLAST";
         //SBC.BatchSize = 100;
         SBC.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;    
         SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mapEMAILID = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("EMAILID", "EMAILID");
         SBC.ColumnMappings.Add(mapEMAILID);
            try
             {
               int k = dtEmails.Rows.Count;    
               SBC.WriteToServer(dtEmails);
               transaction.Commit();
              }
              catch (System.Exception ex)
              {
                 transaction.Rollback();
              }    
              SBC.Close();
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

It is taking very long time to insert.
When ever I stop my execution,the data is still inserting in DB with out Rolling Back

Comment: If by "stop my execution" you mean stopping debug then the rollback will never be reached. When you stop debugging the code exits immediately. 500 000 rows should insert fairly quickly, do you have any varbinary columns?

Comment: I have 2 varchar(max) columns

Comment: The only thing I can recommend by looking at the provider information is check your column mapping(s) and ensure all aligns correctly.